# Flutter PageView pages with different width

Tags: flutter, uipageviewcontroller, pageviews, flutter-pageview

I am wondered, is there a way to show PageView with pages of different width?

So what I need: one page is full-screen width size, and the second one is 0.75 of it (so when user scroll to second page 0.25 of the first one is still visible.

Any ideas on how it might be done? Thanks!

Comment: I wonder, why do you need to use a `pageview` for this, pageview children are meant to be of the same size. Wouldn't a `ListView` make more sense for achieving this?

Comment: please give a picture to elaborate more correctly